# Formatting DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to output a datetime in a 12 hour format. It works for some and then breaks.

Code:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date Before formatting = " + myReader["Date"].ToString());
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(myReader["Date"].ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


    string format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
    Console.WriteLine(myReader["RxNumber"].ToString() + "\t\t" + dt.ToString(format));
}
```

Output:

Connection opened

Date Before formatting = 2013/12/26 11:26:08

```
            12/26/2013 11:26:08 AM
```

Date Before formatting = 2013/12/26 09:02:01

12345           12/26/2013 09:02:01 AM

Date Before formatting = 2013/12/26 09:04:29

123456          12/26/2013 09:04:29 AM

Date Before formatting = 2013/10/28 10:19:26

```
            10/28/2013 10:19:26 AM
```

Date Before formatting = 2014/02/14 12:25:57

7000006         02/14/2014 12:25:57 AM

Date Before formatting = 2014/02/14 13:20:18

System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at test.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\software for testing test608\test\test\Program.cs:line 33
☺Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Could you give us an example of the string value that throws the exception?

Comment: I've updated my question for a better output.

Comment: Your output doesn't match your code. I'm inclined to guess that Michael's answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the database is storing the values in a 24-hour format and you're parsing them into a `DateTime` as a 12-hour format; use this instead:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    myReader["Date"].ToString(),
    "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Once the date is parsed from the database correctly, the output as a 12-hour format is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HH` for military (24hr) time. `hh` is for standard 12 hour time.